# What is `lambda` in Python code? How does it work with `key` arguments to `sorted`, `sum` etc.?

Tags: python, lambda, higher-order-functions

I saw some examples using built-in functions like `sorted`, `sum` etc. that use `key=lambda`.

What does `lambda` mean here? How does it work?

---

<sub>For the general computer science concept of a lambda, see [What is a lambda (function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501).</sub>

<sub>See also [How are lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/how-are-lambdas-useful) for some discussion that no longer meets site standards but which you may find useful.</sub>

Comment: `key` in this case is a keyword argument and has nothing to do with `lambda`.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda

Answer (score 123, accepted):

A [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is an anonymous function:

```
>>> f = lambda: 'foo'
>>> print(f())
foo
```

It is often used in functions such as `sorted()` that take a callable as a parameter (often the `key` keyword parameter). You could provide an existing function instead of a `lambda` there too, as long as it is a callable object.

Take the [`sorted()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) as an example. It'll return the given iterable in sorted order:

```
>>> sorted(['Some', 'words', 'sort', 'differently'])
['Some', 'differently', 'sort', 'words']
```

but that sorts uppercased words before words that are lowercased. Using the `key` keyword you can change each entry so it'll be sorted differently. We could lowercase all the words before sorting, for example:

```
>>> def lowercased(word): return word.lower()
...
>>> lowercased('Some')
'some'
>>> sorted(['Some', 'words', 'sort', 'differently'], key=lowercased)
['differently', 'Some', 'sort', 'words']
```

We had to create a separate function for that, we could not inline the `def lowercased()` line into the `sorted()` expression:

```
>>> sorted(['Some', 'words', 'sort', 'differently'], key=def lowercased(word): return word.lower())
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sorted(['Some', 'words', 'sort', 'differently'], key=def lowercased(word): return word.lower())
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

A `lambda` on the other hand, can be specified directly, inline in the `sorted()` expression:

```
 >>> sorted(['Some', 'words', 'sort', 'differently'], key=lambda word: word.lower())
['differently', 'Some', 'sort', 'words']
```

Lambdas are limited to one expression only, the result of which is the return value.

There are loads of places in the Python library, including built-in functions, that take a callable as keyword or positional argument. There are too many to name here, and they often play a different role.

Answer (score 22):

In Python, `lambda` is a keyword used to define *anonymous functions*(i.e., functions that don't have a name), sometimes called *lambda functions* (after the keyword, which in turn comes [from theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501)).

Let's see some examples:

```
>>> # Define a lambda function that takes 2 parameters and sums them:
>>> lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2 
<function <lambda> at 0x1004b5de8>
>>> 
>>> # We can store the returned value in variable & call it:
>>> addition = lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2
>>> addition(62, 5)
67
>>> addition(1700, 29)
1729
>>> 
>>> # Since it's an expression, we can use it in-line instead:
>>> (lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2)(120, 1)
121
>>> (lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2)(-68, 2)
-66
>>> (lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2)(-68, 2**3)
-60
>>>
```

Now let's see how this works in the context of `sorted`.

Suppose we have a list like so, with a mixture of integers and strings with numeric contents:

```
nums = ["2", 1, 3, 4, "5", "8", "-1", "-10"]
```

and that we would like to sort the values *according to the number they represent*: thus, the result should be `['-10', '-1', 1, '2', 3, 4, '5', '8']`.

If we try to sort it using `sorted`, we get the wrong result:

```
>>> nums = ["2", 1, 3, 4, "5", "8", "-1", "-10"]
>>> sorted(nums) # in 2.x
[1, 3, 4, '-1', '-10', '2', '5', '8']
>>> # In 3.x, an exception is raised instead
```

By using a `key` for `sorted`, however, we can sort the values *according to the result* of applying the `key` function to each value:

```
>>> nums = ["2", 1, 3, 4, "5", "8", "-1", "-10"]
>>> sorted(nums, key=int)
['-10', '-1', 1, '2', 3, 4, '5', '8']
>>>
```

Since `lambda` creates a *callable* (specifically, a function), we can use one for the `key`:

```
>>> names = ["Rishikesh", "aman", "Ajay", "Hemkesh", "sandeep", "Darshan", "Virendra", "Shwetabh"]
>>> names2 = sorted(names)
>>> names2
['Ajay', 'Darshan', 'Hemkesh', 'Rishikesh', 'Shwetabh', 'Virendra', 'aman', 'sandeep']
>>> # Let's use a lambda to get a case-insensitive sort:
>>> names3 = sorted(names, key=lambda name:name.lower())
>>> names3
['Ajay', 'aman', 'Darshan', 'Hemkesh', 'Rishikesh', 'sandeep', 'Shwetabh', 'Virendra']
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

Lambda can be any function. So if you had a function

```
def compare_person(a):
         return a.age
```

You could sort a list of Person (each of which having an age attribute) like this:

```
sorted(personArray, key=compare_person)
```

This way, the list would be sorted by age in ascending order.

Your example contains "lambda" because python has a nifty lambda keyword for defining such functions on the fly. Instead of defining a function compare_person and passing that to sorted, you can also write:

```
sorted(personArray, key=lambda a: a.age)
```

which does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
 >>> sorted(['Some', 'words', 'sort', 'differently'], key=lambda word: word.lower())
```

Actually, above codes can be:

```
>>> sorted(['Some','words','sort','differently'],key=str.lower)
```

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted, key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).