# How to print sorted data on json.load?

Tags: python, json, sorting

I need to print line for line a static json file. I would like to sort this by a key value prior to printing. I have looked at several other examples on stackoverflow, but was unable to find a solution to this particular problem.

My code so far looks like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('items.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for line in data:
        pprint(data)
```

My json looks like this:

```
[
{"version": ["2.8.2"], "license": ["GPL"]},
{"version": ["1.8.8"], "license": ["MIT/X11 License"]},
{"version": ["2.8.5"], "license": ["GPL"]},
{"version": ["1.8.9"], "license": ["MIT/X11 License"]}
]
```

How can I sort it by a key value such as "version" while preserving order?
In this way I can determine at which version the license was changed.

Desired output would look like this:

```
[
{"version": ["1.8.8"], "license": ["MIT/X11 License"]},
{"version": ["1.8.9"], "license": ["MIT/X11 License"]},
{"version": ["2.8.2"], "license": ["GPL"]},
{"version": ["2.8.5"], "license": ["GPL"]}
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: `for line in data: pprint(data)` is never going to give your desired output, so I have to clarify, are you looking to get valid JSON as the output, or do you just want something sorted and pretty?

Comment: Just sorted and pretty in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data is already in dictionary form so something like:

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: x['version'])
```

And then pretty-print that structure.

Edit: you can print the whole structure with one line, by the way:

```
pprint.pprint(sorted_data, indent=4)
```

should look pretty nice.

For more information on the lambda expression, have a look at this SO thread: [What is key=lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda)

Comment: Yes, this does exactly what I wanted. I will read up more about the lamda function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @tonemgub Glad to help! I added a link to a good summary of using lambda. Don't forget to accept whichever answer you like best (I see there is another one that is good too)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sort your list of dicts with an appropriate key function. You *could* use a lambda, but `itemgetter` is more efficient.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter

data_str = '''\
[
    {"version": ["2.8.2"], "license": ["GPL"]},
    {"version": ["1.8.8"], "license": ["MIT/X11 License"]},
    {"version": ["2.8.5"], "license": ["GPL"]},
    {"version": ["1.8.9"], "license": ["MIT/X11 License"]}
]
'''

data = json.loads(data_str)
data.sort(key=itemgetter("version"))
pprint(data)
```

**output**

```
[   {'license': ['MIT/X11 License'], 'version': ['1.8.8']},
    {'license': ['MIT/X11 License'], 'version': ['1.8.9']},
    {'license': ['GPL'], 'version': ['2.8.2']},
    {'license': ['GPL'], 'version': ['2.8.5']}]
```

Comment: Thank you for offering your solution! I am not dealing with a large data set, but I assume by efficiency you mean itemgetter is faster compared to lambda?

Comment: @tonemgub Yes, `itemgetter` is faster than using an equivalent lambda, but it's good to know both ways, because sometimes you need a key function that does more than what `itemgetter` can do.