# Working of python's sort key

Tags: python, lambda

```
class Solution(object):
    def moveZeroes(self, nums):
        nums.sort(key =lambda x : 1 if x == 0 else 0)
        return nums
```

My function looks like above.
I don't seem to understand how code `key =lambda x : 1 if x == 0 else 0`  works.

I also tried to change the lambda function to:

```
def getKey(item):
    if item == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

But don't seem to understand how key=1 or 0, affects the result.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: Sorting with a key means sorting using the value given by the key function as the indication of where to place the item. In this case, `0` is before `1`, so all the items that produce key `0` will be placed earlier than all the items that produce key `1`.

Comment: think of the `key` as a "mapping" of your original data to something else (in this case `1`s and `0`s). These `1`s and `0`s are then sorted as you would imagine and then the mapping is reversed to reveal the initial objects but  this time sorted.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks you guys, i have tried to write the answer below.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks you guy, i have tried to write the answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is key=lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @khelwood and @Ev. Kounis, i tried to wrote the answer myself.

the lambda function could rewrite like below:

```
def getKey(item):
    if item == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

when i us a map function like :

```
a = [1, 2, 0, 2, 0]
print map(getKey, a)
```

It results `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

And then the sort function will sort the original list based on the output above. Let's recall the `moveZeroes` function:

```
class Solution(object):
    def moveZeroes(self, nums):
        nums.sort(key =lambda x : 1 if x == 0 else 0)
        return nums

print Solution().moveZeroes([1, 2, 0, 2, 0])
output: [1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: take a look at [this](https://repl.it/repls/VerifiableGrotesqueBasilisk)

Answer (score 1):

Just to bring a little clarification. `key` is applied to your data before the element's are sorted. Typically you put things like `len` which is giving a usefull measure to compare the elements against each other.

However in this case it's exploiting that functionality, basically giving `0` the highest key value of `1` and the rest just get's a value `0` which brings all the `0`s to the end of the list. 
That's why the list is actually not sorted after that operation, just the `0`s stick at the end

```
nums.sort(key =lambda x : 1 if x == 0 else 0)
```