# Sort a list of dictionaries by values with some items missing

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict of lists like this:

```
a = [
   {'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'},
   {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'},
   {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'},
   {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'},
   {'id': 'ab5'}
]
```

I want to sort `a` by the value of `p`. If dict doesn't has `p`, put it behind.
I tried this way:

```
print sorted(a, key=lambda i: i.get('p'))
```

and got result:

```
[{'id': 'ab5'}, {'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'}, {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'}, {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'}, {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'}]
```

but want to get is:

```
[{'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'}, {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'}, {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'}, {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'},{'id': 'ab5'}]
```

What can I do to get the correct result with easier way?

Comment: The above code will work for `python2` but not for `python3`, as it will fail with an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'` for `'id': 'ab5'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python2 and python3 both, you can do as follows, where I assume if the value of `p` is missing, I am assuming `sys.maxsize` value, which will ensure that if we have missing values for `p`, they are always at the end of the list

```
import sys
a = [
   {'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'},
   {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'},
   {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'},
   {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'},
   {'id': 'ab5'}
]

print(sorted(a, key=lambda i: i.get('p', sys.maxsize)))
```

Which will give you

```
[{'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'}, {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'}, {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'}, {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'}, {'id': 'ab5'}]
```

Another solution if comparing to `sys.maxsize` is overkill, is to separate out the dictionaries without the key `p`, sort the remaining dictionary which contain the key `p`, and then extend it by attaching the non `p` key dictionaries like so. This also avoids us from providing a default value for `p` in `item.get()`

```
import sys
a = [
   {'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'},
   {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'},
   {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'},
   {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'},
   {'id': 'ab5'}
]

#Dictionaries with key p
p_items = [item for item in a if 'p' in item.keys()]

#Dictionaries not with key p
non_p_items = [item for item in a if 'p' not in item.keys()]

#Sort the p-key dictionaries
result = sorted(p_items, key=lambda i: i.get('p'))

#Attach non p-key dictionay items at end
result.extend(non_p_items)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
a = [
   {'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'},
   {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'},
   {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'},
   {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'},
   {'id': 'ab5'}
]

print(sorted(a, key=lambda i: i.get('p', "NA"))) #Setting a string as a default value. 
#python 3  --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829732/sorting-a-mixed-list-of-ints-and-strings
print(sorted(a, key=lambda v: (isinstance(v.get('p', "NA"), str), v.get('p', "NA"))))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'}, {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'}, {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'}, {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'}, {'id': 'ab5'}]
```

Comment: Are you sure a string can be compared to a int? `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` For python 3

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that I prefer that doesn't use `lambda`:

```
import sys
from operator import methodcaller

a = [
   {'p': 3, 'id': 'ab1'},
   {'p': 10, 'id': 'ab2'},
   {'p': 5, 'id': 'ab3'},
   {'p': 8, 'id': 'ab4'},
   {'id': 'ab5'}
]

print(sorted(a, key=methodcaller('get', 'p', sys.maxsize)))
```