# How does lambda works in key argument in sorted?

Tags: python-3.x

We have, for example:

```
rows = [
{'fname': 'Brian', 'lname': 'Jones', 'uid': 1003},
{'fname': 'David', 'lname': 'Beazley', 'uid': 1002},
{'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Cleese', 'uid': 1001},
{'fname': 'Big', 'lname': 'Jones', 'uid': 1004}
]
```

and

```
rows_by_fname = sorted(rows, key=lambda r: r['fname'])
```

this,

```
key=lambda r: r['fname']
```

how does it work? as my understanding that r is input for lambda function, right? and that r must be equal to rows, but we never called that lambda function and passed any arguments so what gets assigned to r and how?

Comment: `sorted` calls the lambda function with each of the elements of `rows` as arguments, and sorts it according to the results of the function, in this case the `fname`

Comment: just read the doc [key functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

Comment: yes, that makes sense @MaartenFabré, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda), [What is key=lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `r` parameter in your function `lambda r: r['fname']` receives each element of the array `rows`. And then, the lambda function define the keys that will be sorted by the function `sorted()`. In this case, the keys will be `fname`.

Is the `sorted()` that calls the lambda function. The reason to use lambda is because the function will be used only once.

Edit: Read the [key docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

Comment: but Maarten Frabré said sorted calls the lambda functon with each of the elements or rows, whereas you said it receives the array rows.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. My explanation wasn't clearly enough.

Comment: edit your answer then, so I can close this thread @MatheusReis