# Python - Iterating through a list -Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, loops, lambda

Below I have created a function which iterates through a list of numbers and selects the last 3 digits from each numbers and puts them as new numbers in another list.I also sort them from smallest to largest.However, I see a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" message. What is wrong with my code? Also how could. we do the same thing with a lambda function?

```
ids = [1600,1500,1800,1900,1700]
alist=ids
sorted_ids=[]
def last_four(alist):
    for element in alist: 
        values=str(element)
        sorted_ids.append(values[1:4])
    return sorted(sorted_ids)

print(last_four(alist))
```

[image: Code above]

Thank you very much!

Comment: To select the last 3 digits you can use `str(value)[:-3]` instead of `str(value)[1:4]`. This way no matter the length of the number it always take the last 3 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ids = [1600,1500,1800,1900,1700]
alist=ids
sorted_ids=[]
def last_four(alist):
    for element in alist: 
        values=str(element)
        sorted_ids.append(values[1:4])
    return sorted(sorted_ids)

print(last_four(alist))
```

results in :
[image]

> for your second question here is the code

```
last_four = list(map(lambda element: str(element)[1:4], alist))
print(sorted(last_four))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to works well already.

If you want to use lambda, you can write your code something like this. (Which is same with the [answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321529/8423105), only the difference is that you can immediately use sorted function without deliberately converting a map object into a list object.)

```
def main():
    ids = [1600, 1500, 1800, 1900, 1700]
    alist = ids
    sorted_last_four = sorted(map(lambda element: str(element)[1:4], alist))
    print(sorted_last_four)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you are not familiar with using lambda, or you want to get some intuition of how to use lambda and sorted functions together, you can read this [answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13669265/8423105).

Good luck.