# What exactly DOES a Lambda do?

Tags: python, function, lambda

Okay, So I've been seeing a TON of Lambda functions in Python code. I keep looking at previously asked questions about Lambdas, but they don't explain what they DO. Do they set a variable? For example, if I did Lambda x: x + 1, would it set the variable X to equal x+1? Also, How do you print the value of a Lambda? Thanks

Comment: A lambda is just a function. It does whatever the function body tells it to do. `x: x + 1` will take one parameter and return the result of adding one to the passed in argument. Presumably `x` is expected to be a number. Should be equivalent to `def foo(x): return x + 1`.

Comment: @deceze: also potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda . (edited) it has more votes, so I floagged your duplicate target as a duplicate of the above.

Comment: They're essentially shorthand for a single function which evaluates and returns exactly one expression. Nothing more, nothing less. They don't need to be named like traditional `def`s and can simply be declared inline wherever a function object is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `lambda x: x+1` will take an argument `x` and return `x+1`, equivalent to `def foo(x): return x+1`, these are also called anonymous functions.

Lambdas are extremely useful while passing a function as an argument. Let's give you an example. Suppose you have a 2D list of tuples:

```
l = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',1)]
```

And you want to sort the list using the second item in each tuple. Manually it will take a lot of code to do this manually, but with lambdas you can pass a lambda function as a `key` to `sort` method or `sorted()` like this:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

And there are more examples!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lambda are anonymous functions.