# Can someone please explain this line of code for sorting list using key as parameter?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
gIn = list()
egIn = [101, 'Python', 102, 'Machine Learning', 'Deep Learning', 1]
def function1 (lst1):
    lst1.sort(key=lambda e: (isinstance(e, str), e))
    return lst1
print(function1(egIn))
```

Why are we using `(isinstance(e, str), e)` in this function? i understood `isinstance(e,str)` but why is that other `e` ? what does it do and how the `key` parameter is used

Comment: Please use the code tag to add the code part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is key=lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

Here is explanation what does that piece of code do.

List method sort can have key as a parameter. It is a function which returns value and list is sorted according to that value.

`(isinstance(e, str), e)` is a tuple. For string `"abc"` it is `(True, "abc")` and for Integer `5` it is `(False, 5)`.

So it sorts first strings to the end of the list and order strings in end of the list to alphabetical order.