# Python sort function explanation

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I found the following line of code which I'm unable to google as it has a custom function. Can someone please explain this?

```
list.sort(key=lambda v: map(int, v.split('.')))
```

I know this sorts a list but I want to understand which sort is it and how it works.

Comment: Assuming "which sort is it" means what algorithm, see the duplicate. If your question is something else, please make your question more specific.

Comment: @khelwood I've gone through the duplicated question but it only explains the general sort function. however, in this function I want to understand what does lamda means here, what values would pass in v , how ':' operator works in a custom function and does map works normally as we see in other languages? let me know if can reopen it.

Comment: That would be several different questions. If it wasn't closed as a duplicate, it would be closed as too broad. But see also [What is key=lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13669252/3890632)

Comment: It's for sorting version numbers. Given strings `"2.7.17", "3.9.5","3.10.0"`it will sort them on major, minor, patch as you might expect. It's not robust and will fail on `"3.10.0rc1"`.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the link you shared and the info about this question. should I delete this question then?
BoarGules Thanks man that was quite helpful.