# Removing duplicate keys from list of dictionary, keep only that key-value where value is maximum

Tags: python, algorithm

From a list like :

```
mylist = [{'x':2020 , 'y':20},{'x':2020 , 'y':30},{'x':2021 , 'y':10},{'x':2021 , 'y':5}]
```

I want to keep all 'x' unique and 'y' to be the maximum where 'x' is the same.

I am trying to get the output as:

```
mylist_unique =  [{'x':2020 , 'y':30},{'x':2021 , 'y':10}]
```

I have implemented it in a very naive way:

```
res =[]
temp = {}
print(len(temp))

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print(mylist[i])
    for k,v in mylist[i].items():
        print(mylist[i]['x'],temp.keys(),mylist[i]['y'])
        if mylist[i]['x'] not in temp.keys() or mylist[i]['y'] > (temp[mylist[i]['x']]) :
            print(k)
            temp.update({mylist[i]['x']:mylist[i]['y']})

print(temp)
for k,v in temp.items():
    res.append({'x':k,'y':v})
print(res)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [{'x': 2020, 'y': 20}, {'x': 2020, 'y': 30}, {'x': 2021, 'y': 10}, {'x': 2021, 'y': 5}]

mylist_unique = [{'x': key, 'y': max(item['y'] for item in values)}
                 for key, values in groupby(mylist, lambda dct: dct['x'])]
print(mylist_unique)
```

This yields

```
[{'x': 2020, 'y': 30}, {'x': 2021, 'y': 10}]
```

Comment: what is lambda dct: dct['x'])

Comment: @richaverma: This is how groupby works. You can feed it a key function that accumulates the values based on a key (in your example `x` from every dict in your list).

Comment: @richaverma The keyword `lambda` is used to define anonymous inline functions. `groupby`'s second argument must be a function. You could define that function beforehand by writing `def function_for_groupby(dct): return dct['x']` and then `groupby(mylist, function_for_groupby)` or you can define the function inline without giving it a name, using `lambda`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233508/what-exactly-is-lambda-in-python

Comment: what is passed in argument during function call?

Comment: How would this code look if I mad multiple keys in a dict and I would like to retain all of them but filter by specifc one only?

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code, should do what you look for:

```
ht = dict()
for elem in mylist:
    if elem['x'] in ht:
        ht[elem['x']] = max(ht[elem['x']],elem['y'])
    else:
        ht[elem['x']]=elem['y']

mylist_unique=[]

for key in ht:
    mylist_unique.append({'x':key,'y':ht[key]})
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple groupby should work for you as you want unique `x` we groupby on x and then find the max value of y

```
import itertools
mylist = [{'x':2020 , 'y':20},{'x':2020 , 'y':30},{'x':2021 , 'y':10},{'x':2021 , 'y':5}]
mylist1=[]
for key, group in itertools.groupby(mylist,lambda x:x["x"]):
    max_y=0
    for thing in group:
        max_y=max(max_y,thing["y"])
    mylist1.append({"x":key,"y":max_y})
print(mylist1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and groupby to do this in one line:

```py
from itertools import groupby

list(map(lambda a:{'x':a[0], 'y':max(map(lambda b: b['y'], a[1]))}, groupby(mylist, lambda c: c['x'])))
```

This yields

```py
[{'x': 2020, 'y': 30}, {'x': 2021, 'y': 10}]
```