# How to correct this problem occurring in replace()? Python

Tags: python, replace

I have a sentence as follows:

```
s="This is my cat who is my ally and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one."
```

I want to replace certain words in the sentence with other words. Example:

> cat with bat, ally with protector.

Now the problem occurs with similar words. For example ally and finally

```
s="This is my cat who is my ally and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one."
for r in (("cat", "bat"),("ally", "protector")):
    s = s.replace(*r)
print(s)
```

This should give me:

> This is my bat who is my protector and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one.

But it gives me the following output affecting **finally because of ally**:

> This is my bat who is my protector and this is my dog who has started to finprotector act like one.

It affects finally and converts it to `finprotector`. I don't want this. How can I solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use regex. `re.sub('\bally\b', 'protector', s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions with a dictionary, [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)
, and [`lambda`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5233508/967621) like so:

```
import re

s = "This is my cat who is my ally and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one."
dct = {
    'cat': 'bat',
    'ally': 'protector'
}

regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, dct.keys())) + r')\b')
print(regex.sub(lambda match: dct[match.group(0)], s))
# This is my bat who is my protector and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one.
```

Note that `\b` denotes word break, which allows `ally` and `, ally` , but not `finally`, to be matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can include spaces in your `replace` to only select individual words.

```
s="This is my cat who is my ally and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one."
for r in ((" cat ", " bat "),(" ally ", " protector ")):
    s = s.replace(*r)
print(s)
```

```
This is my bat who is my protector and this is my dog who has started to finally act like one.
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot buddy. :D You saved the day.

Comment: This will however not work if the string is `my cat, who is my ally` which would make more grammatical sense. You should use Regular-Expression here ideally.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try the regular expressions and the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module (particulary the [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method)?

```py
import re

line = re.sub(r'\bally\b', 'protector', s)
```

Comment: How to give more than one condition like cat->bat, ally->protector ....

Comment: I would say several calls of the `re.sub`. Take into account that the method has an optional argument `count`: by default, it changes only the leftmost appearance of the replacing pattern.